# IPN de PayPal error en notificación

Tags: wordpress, paypal

trataré de ser breve y concreto, pero esto es un lío...

A través del sandbox, estoy realizando pruebas para un sistema de cursos. la prueba aparentemente es exitosa, el usuario paga y es devuelto al sitio, pero no tiene acceso al curso y el pedido queda como "pendiente". La configuración de IPN es correcta y está activada la opción de redireccionamiento. Al revisar el historial de IPN encontramos que las notificaciones si se ejecutan, pero no se entregan, permanecen en estado "intentando" por un rato, hasta que luego de 7 u 8 intentos finalmente quedan como "erróneo" y no hay código de respuesta HTTP (esta vacío), por lo que no se puede saber la razón del error. He probado en live, y resultó el mismo problema.

Pensando que el problema pudiera estar en el servidor, instalamos todo el sistema (wp + learpress) en otro servidor, y en este caso todo ha sido correcto y exitoso. El curso se activa, el usuario tiene acceso y en el historial de IPN aparece la notificación como "enviada" con estatus "200". Luego probamos a colocar el sistema en otro dominio dentro del mismo servidor donde no funciona, y realizamos el mismo proceso, nuevamente todo fue correcto. Entonces, probamos a instalar el sistema en un par de subdominios más dentro del mismo dominio con el que no funciona la notificacion IPN y el resultado fue erróneo también, no funciona ni con el dominio principal ni con subdominios, pero si funciona colocando en otro servidor u otro dominio dentro del mismo servidor...

Concluimos que el problema tiene algo que ver más con el dominio que con el hosting, pero no tenemos idea de cual pudiera ser la razón por la que paypal no puede comunicarse con el listener de la pasarela en este dominio... ya revisamos el estatus y reputación del dominio, todo está ok (no está en blacklist y el ssl es correcto y usa algoritmo SHA256).

Hicimos pruebas con el simulador IPN y el resultado es "IPN was not sent, and the handshake was not verified" y la consola muestra un error 400 Bad Request (pero sin mayor detalle).

Sin tener que dar más datos o evidencias sobre mi caso (no hay código que revisar porque el sistema está bien), a alguien más le ha sucedido esto o algo parecido? Pudieron solucionarlo?

Insisto, el problema no es la configuración de IPN, no es el sistema (wp + learnpress) y aparentemente no es el servidor, porque todo funciona bien si lo colocamos en otro dominio (aún incluso, sin configurar IPN desde paypal, eso es lo más curioso) y ya nos apoyaron a revisar si hay algún bloqueo o log de error en el servidor, pero nada, es como si el servidor nunca hubiera recibido un intento de comunicación por parte de la IPN, ni rastro. Ya busqué en el foro de la comunidad de PayPal, ya les pedí ayuda (no responden) y ya busque otras posibles preguntas en este foro y otros pero no encontré ninguna con este problema puntual.

Gracias.

Comment: Revisa que no sea un problema de IPs y de firewall, quizas teneis bloqueos activos a las ips de paypal por cualquier motivo, desactiva el firewall a ver que sucede

Comment: @masterguru, gracias por el comentario. Supuse algo similar en algún momento, pero el soporte del hosting ya me ayudó a verificar eso. Este detalle no es a nivel IP ni firewall, porque como lo indiqué, todo funciona perfectamente si lo coloco en otro dominio en el mismo servidor (por lo tanto aplica la misma IP y el mismo firewall), así que el problema es a nivel del dominio. Sigo buscando...

Comment: Ok, entendido, no tenia por seguro si la ip te cambiaba o no en los distintos dominios, por eso mi comentario. Pues si que es raro, si, suerte!

Comment: Sí, es un servidor compartido, no indiqué ese dato. Pero gracias de cualquier manera. Saludos.